# How to I remove components in the React-devtools tree from a given parent node?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

In this case I just want it to go from 'App' down, though I may want to have other scenarios

[image]

I tried location matches `ExpoRoot$` but that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. The only way i figured is to put the item you want to remove in React.Suspense component.

In my case, it look like this:

```
const LikeSection = React.lazy(() => import("../LikeSection/LikeSection"))

export interface CommentProps {
    id: string
    likesCount: LikeSectionProps
    commentBodyInfo: CommentBodyProps
    replies?: Promise<CommentProps[] | undefined> | undefined
}

const Comment: FC<CommentProps> = ({ id, likesCount, commentBodyInfo }) => {
    return (
        <div
            id={id}
            className={styles["comment"]}>
            <CommentDetailsContext.Provider value={{ id: +id }}>
                <React.Suspense>
                    <LikeSection {...likesCount} />
                </React.Suspense>

                <CommentBody {...commentBodyInfo} />
            </CommentDetailsContext.Provider>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And then you just click that button in React Dev Tools:
[React dev tools suspend button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS2sC.png)

Comment: I think you have it backwards, in your example I only want to see the LikeSection and nothing else above it.